# Is it possible to make a page only scroll down/up for only a set amount of times using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, animation, scroll

What I am trying to accomplish is letting users only be able to scroll a maximum amount of 5 times on a page (one for each section), I will set a counter and increment/decrement it every time the user scrolls down/up respectively to determine where they are currently at on the page.

A quick example:

```
var counter = 1;

$(document).scroll(function(){
if (counter == 1) {
//fire first function/animation
} else if (counter == 2) ( // if user is scrolling down ) {
//fire second function/animation
counter++;
} else if ((counter == 3) && ( // if user is scrolling down ) {
//fire third function/animation
counter++;
}
})
```

and so on...

Comment: Yes, the pattern is possible.

Comment: `$(document).scroll(function(e){ if(count==1){...} else {e.preventDefault();} }` I think will probably work. The **e.preventDefault()** in the *else* prevents the default scroll action (not tested).